# Calling a ClassA.Method() as ClassB.Method() but only affecting ClassA values, both classes are deriving from the same BaseClass

Tags: c#, object, casting, polymorphism, state

In this example I am building an automation library for browsers. There is a base class called Mouse, and derived classes called RoboticMouse and HumanMouse.

Lets say I instantiate the mouse as HumanMouse but in one specific occasion I want it to behave as a RoboticMouse, for example, on parts where I need it to move the mouse faster, what I tried doing is:

```
Mouse m = new HumanMouse();
m.Move();
(m as RoboticMouse).Move();
```

But I get a NullReferenceException since the Mouse m was initialized as a HumanMouse and not a RoboticMouse.

I could do:

```
Mouse m = new HumanMouse();
m.Move();
m = new RoboticMouse(); m.Move();
```

But this way the values inside it would be re-initialized and I want to keep the state intact, for example, for tracking the mouse position.

EDIT:
Simpler example:

This does not work as instance is ClassB, and throws null.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        BaseClass instance = new ClassB();

        instance.Increment();
        Console.WriteLine(instance.Value);

        (instance as ClassA).Increment();
        Console.WriteLine(instance.Value);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class BaseClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public virtual void Increment()
    {
        Value++;
    }
}

class ClassA : BaseClass
{
    public override void Increment()
    {
        Value += 2;
    }
}

class ClassB : BaseClass
{
    public override void Increment()
    {
        Value += 4;
    }
}
```

If I follow the suggestion given making ClassB inherit from ClassA:

```
class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public override void Increment()
    {
        Value += 4;
    }
}
```

And try to cast it:

```
public static void Run()
    {
        BaseClass instance = new ClassB();

        instance.Increment();
        Console.WriteLine(instance.Value);

        (instance as ClassA).Increment();
        Console.WriteLine(instance.Value);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

It still runs ClassB version of the method...

Comment: The only case when this is valid is if `HumanMouse` extends `RoboticMouse`, which on its turn extends `Mouse`. However, you could create the `Mouse` to accept actors. It could accept both `Human` and `Robot` and you could act on the Mouse instance via the actor - which IMHO is closer to the actual scenario as casting the mouse to something.

Comment: Can you see my edit with a simpler example? @ZorgoZ

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not know how to conver from `HumanMouse` to `RoboticMouse`.

When you are using `new` you are creating effectively a new reference with new values, so it makes sense to see what you see.

Two ways around it. If a `HumanMouse` is indeed a `RoboticMouse`, then extend the `HumanMouse` from the `RoboticMouse`

If the `HumanMouse` is castable to a `RoboticMouse`, then you can declare how the cast is made by using the [user-defined-conversion-operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators).

**Edit based on question edits**

Let me give you an example with animals.

Let's say that `ClassA` is an animal and `ClassB` is a Cat. So the `Cat` extends the animal and set a new behavior for the `Move` function.

The cat will always be an animal, but not every animal is a cat. That's why

```
// This works
Animal a = new Cat();
// This does not work
Cat a = new Animal();
```

Now when you assign a cat to an animal and you have overriden the `Move` function, that means that the cat will always move as a cat whether or not you access it as an animal. You can't cast a cat to an animal as it is already an animal. `(cat as Animal)` does nothing.

Same way you can't cast `classB` to `classA` since B is already an A and will always behave as a B.

### Edit 2: Possible solution

```
public abstract class Mouse {

    public int x {get; set;}
    public int y {get; set;}

    public Mouse(x,y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public virtual void Move() {
        this.x++;
        this.y++;
    }

    public virtual void Move(x, y) {
        this.x+= x;
        this.y+= y;
    }
}

public class HumanMouse: Mouse {
   // whatever
   public HumanMouse(): base(1,1) {
   }
}

public class RoboticMouse: Mouse {
   public static int
   // whatever
   public RoboticMouse(): base(2,2) {
   }
}


Mouse m = new HumanMouse();
m.Move();
m.Move(1,2); 
// or
Mouse m2 = new RoboticMouse();
m.Move();
m.Move(m2.x,m2.y);
```

Comment: The HumanMouse is a Mouse, RoboticMouse is a Mouse. What are my options here?
EDIT: tried deriving HumanMouse from RoboticMouse, and casting (m as RoboticMouse).Move(); still runs HumanMouse.Move();

Comment: If they are castable (interchangeable) then use user defined conversion operator, to convert one to the other. If you want it to move as a `RoboticMouse`, then create a secondary `MoveAsRobot` in the `HumanMouse` and call that.

Comment: Can you see my edit with a simpler example? @Athanasios Kataras

Comment: Check the update on the answer that explains why your code does not work as you intend it to.

Comment: Thanks, the animal analogy is good, but you mentioned "if they are intercheangable", could you give that a meaning with your animals analogy? How would they be castable?

Comment: A long and an int are interchangeable as long as the long is less than an in precision. If you can use one type or the other without losing too much information, then they are interchangeable. If for instance I have two implementations for Animal in a different namespace and those two differ in a small part, then they are interchangeable. DTOs and Poco objects for instance are interchangeable.

Comment: The HumanMouse and RoboticMouse only differ on the method implementation(for now), does that count?

Comment: It does, but it does not make sense conceptually. I'll update with a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: So the solution is passing the position from the object to the other one, almost like cloning?

Comment: Pretty much. If you want a person to move as a cat, you won't turn him to a cat. You will adjust the speed and step distance, based on the knowledge you have from the cat.

Comment: Thats the only solution? I think I could clone it for these specific rare cases, dont know if its that big of a smell because its gonna be used not often

Comment: It's not the only solution. You can opt for creating global constants with movement related information, you can create action factory and get even movement functions from there, there are plenty of options. Depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Do you have any idea on a design pattern that would meet my requirements, or what pattern am I implementing here without knowing?

Comment: No, because I don't know your business or what exactly would need to be done in Move functions.

Comment: That would be probably suited in another question at softwareengineering.stackexchange, or, at SO itself?

Comment: Indeed @JoaoVitor, this would be better suited there.